# Table spacing issue with IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer

please see http://www.cookandheat.com

I have an issue with the spacing of the 4 small images on the right.
All ok in Firefox,Chrome but spreading out with IE9..

```
 CSS looks like this:

 .fixedtable{
width: 90px;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: right;
vertical-align: top;
```

}

Thanks for any advice to solve this..

Rich

Note - this is the sample HTML (moved from comment):

```
<tr>
    <td class="fixedtable">
        <img src="images/service-now.jpg" alt="aga service" width="90" height="150" align="right" />
    </td>
    <td class="fixedtable">
        <img src="images/aga-cosmetics.jpg" alt="aga cosmetics" width="90" height="150" align="right" />
    </td>
    <td class="fixedtable">
        <img src="images/aga-installations.jpg" alt="aga installations" width="90" height="150" align="right" />
    </td>
    <td class="fixedtable" >
        <img src="images/regions-covered.jpg" alt="aga south west" width="90" height="150" align="right" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please post the corresponding HTML as well.

Comment: Im trying to but not letting me

Comment: <td  class="fixedtable" ><img src="images/service-now.jpg" alt="aga service" width="90" height="150" align="right" /></td>
        <td  class="fixedtable" ><img src="images/aga-cosmetics.jpg" alt="aga cosmetics" width="90" height="150" align="right" /></td>
        <td  class="fixedtable" ><img src="images/aga-installations.jpg" alt="aga installations" width="90" height="150" align="right" /></td>
        <td  class="fixedtable" ><img src="images/regions-covered.jpg" alt="aga south west" width="90" height="150" align="right" /></td>

Comment: Sorry, seems I can only enter so much text..

Comment: As I can see, your issue is not with the images, but with the overall section spreading out too far.  I suspect this has something to do with 'transitional' DTD declaration.  Try using 'strict' instead and see if you have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked this in broswer lab. It seems you've fixed the problem.

> As I can see, your issue is not with the images, but with the overall
>   section spreading out too far. I suspect this has something to do with
>   'transitional' DTD declaration. Try using 'strict' instead and see if
>   you have the same problem. – Aleks G Sep 26 at 19:06

All credit goes to him! You should remove this question or answer it yourself.